# sync vs async for images

Tags: mount, fstab, synchronization, disk-image

I have to use `ext4` image file in `btrfs`, because Dropbox requires `ext4` as file system. In `fstab` mount options I've set `async`, but I'm not sure about this.

What are the pros and cons of `async` and `sync` flags for a disk image? Which one is preferable?

I personally think that it is better to let host file system (`btrfs` in my case) handle handle `sync` by itself, so `sync` option is better. Am I right?

Comment: Please post the whole line from `fstab` you are talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I personally think that it is better to let host FS (btrfs in my case) handle handle sync by itself, so sync ption is better. Am I right?

If I understand you correctly, then no :-).  (But it's not entirely clear, and maybe you meant to write "async option is better", not "sync ption").

The loopback device (used for mounting filesystem images) respects sync requests, effectively converting them to `fsync()`.  Then the underlying filesystem will convert these back to sync requests on the block device, or whatever.  So even for a filesystem image, adding the `sync` option  will make all writes fully synchronous (and hence slower).

Unless you have another reason, you can mount without these options and let it default to `async`.  All `fsync()` requests inside the mounted image will be respected as normal.